# Removing certain words from sentences in a list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list that contains certain sentences and words, like:

```
res = ['Today is a great day', 'lunch @myplace', 'make sure to check this link: https://']
```

and I want to delete only the words that start with '@' or words that contain 'https', and not the whole sentence that contains that certain word, how do I go about doing that? Right now, I have the following:

```
words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in res]  
words_cleaned = [word for word in words_filtered if 'http' not in word and not word.startswith('@')]
```

when printing words_cleaned, the words have indeed been deleted from the list but so has the whole sentence. It returns ['today is a great day'] But I want it to return ['today is a great day', 'lunch', 'make sure to check this link:']

Comment: That's because `words_filtered` should actually be named `sentences_filtered`, so that later on you'll see that `[... for word in words_filtered ...]` isn't what you want because it does `[for sentence in sentences_filtered]`, but you want to split each sentence into _individual words_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Praise the power of comprehensions here:

```
res = ['Today is a great day', 'lunch @myplace', 'make sure to check this link: https://']

words_cleaned = [" ".join([
                    words for words in sentence.split()
                    if 'https:' not in words and not words.startswith('@')])
                    for sentence in res]

print(words_cleaned)
```

This yields

```
['Today is a great day', 'lunch', 'make sure to check this link:']
```

---

Or, as `@jpp` points out, use

```
words_cleaned = [" ".join([
                    words for words in sentence.split()
                    if not ('https' in words or words.startswith('@'))])
                    for sentence in res]
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, `not ('https' in words or words.startswith('@'))`

Comment: Also, you don't really need a list comprehension as an argument to `" ".join`: you can use a generator, which is faster and more readable.

Comment: @ForceBru, That's not true. `str.join` works faster with a list. It's one of the few instances where this is the case.

Comment: @ForceBru: `str.join()` needs to iterate over a generator twice (generating a list), that's why it's faster to use a list in the first place.